# Lua (g hub api) mouse not moving

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software, lua-api

I have a problem with Lua mouse script using G hub api. Everything works except for mouse-move functions, for example MoveMouseTo or MoveMouseRelative. Even MoveMouseWheel works fine. Here is my code. Thank you for any feedback.

There are no error logs. Text prints out. [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR80e.png)

Comment: `MoveMouseTo(0,0)` should immediately move the cursor to the upper left corner of the screen.  What behavior do you see instead?

Comment: Cursor stays at the same place and console logs are printing

Answer (score 0):

Try to use function `SmoothMoveMouseTo(x_in_pixels, y_in_pixels)` instead of `MoveMouseTo()`

```
-- set your game screen resolution here
local width  = 1920
local height = 1080

function SmoothMoveMouseTo(x_target, y_target)
   local speed = 1000  -- mouse cursor speed in pixels per second
   local prev_dist = math.huge
   local attempts = 0
   repeat
      local tm = GetRunningTime()
      Sleep(10)
      local x, y = GetMousePosition()
      tm = (GetRunningTime() - tm) * .001
      x = x_target - math.max(0, math.min(width,  math.floor(x * (width  - 1) / 65535 + .5)))
      y = y_target - math.max(0, math.min(height, math.floor(y * (height - 1) / 65535 + .5)))
      local ax, ay = math.abs(x), math.abs(y)
      if ax < 1 and ay < 1 then
         break
      end
      local dist = (x*x + y*y) ^.5
      local dx = math.floor(math.min(ax, math.max(-ax, speed * x / dist * tm)) + .5)
      local dy = math.floor(math.min(ay, math.max(-ay, speed * y / dist * tm)) + .5)
      MouseMoveRelative(dx, dy)
      if dist < prev_dist then
         prev_dist = dist
         attempts = 0
      else
         attempts = attempts + 1
      end
   until attempts > 10
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   .... (your code here)
end
```

For example, `SmoothMoveMouseTo(1920/2, 1080/2)` to move to the center of the screen